# Confused about client side rendering and server side rendering when using a framework like Vue

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to wrap my head around difference of SSR vs CSR when using a framework like Vue.  Wouldn't it *always* be CSR since you'd use Vue Router or a similar mechanism to navigate?

When I think of SSR, I think of something like Rails where the server loads up a different route and has an ERB file it loads up to show.  Are there are any examples of how you would set up SSR and vue?

Comment: Take a look at Nuxt.js (https://nuxtjs.org/) It will explain everything to you. :)

Comment: What I can tell you by now is: 
Frontend Frameworks are as you say normally build on clientSide and Process everything on clientSide. SSR with an Framework like Vue works like this: 
Your Site will be generated by the Server and will be preprocessed what you then get from the Server as a User is the already build complete DOM. dynamic Stuff of course will still rely on client Side, but the initial loading power now switches to the server instead of the user :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue is primarily client side framework - rendering is done by JS running in the client's browser. Your app has (usually) only one `index.html`. That html file contains almost NO html. It only loads tons of JS...

This brings (at least) 2 challenges:

1. Crawlers (Google, but also Twitter/FB etc. for sharing) do not execute JS (or if they do, there is a big "wait in queue" penalty before your site is indexed) so they do not see **any content**. This is problem...
2. When the page being loaded is non-trivial (using lots of components/components rendering huge amount of HTML/components which needs some additional data from API), the initial render can still take a considerable amount of time. This is bad user experience - page loads, user sees nothing and after some time, content appears...

To solve this problems, SSR is introduced. 1st page request is pre-rendered on the server so the client (be it crawler or user) receives something meaningful to index/see and after that, Vue takes the control and everything else happens only on the client again...

Comment: thanks!  Regarding #2 listed above about the initial render of a site taking long.  I thought that was the whole reasoning behind splitting JS into chunks, lazy loading, dynamically loaded components, etc, right?   
Is SSR just an alternative way to solve faster rendering?

Comment: The techniques you are mentioning helps only to reduce the amount of JS code downloaded and parsed on 1st load. It doesn't help you if you have lots of components or rendering non-trivial HTML to the page (or page is waiting for some data from AJAX calls). That will still take time. So pre-rendering on server gives you faster First Contentful Paint (FCP)